# Error when importing .qml component in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created the "BottomBar.qml" component in the UI folder and when I import it into the main.qml file it is giving me an error. could you help please

BottomBar.qml
[image: Component BottomBar]

main.qml
[image: main.qml]

Error message
[image: Error]

I'm following a tutorial and doing exactly the same as the video but it doesn't work. I tried deleting the entire project and creating it again but to no avail.

Comment: Can you share the link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tq-E6lqO6tM&t=515s

Minute 7:00

Comment: He uses a qrc file to list all the available QML files, you can see it on the left in his project tree. I guess he uses an older version of QtCreator which has a slightly different project template that automatically creates the qrc file.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: During the video it does not show the contents of this file. Would you have any documentation on how to create it in version 6.4 of QT? I tried looking in the documentation but I couldn't find how to create it.

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=CTbpS0PN-JQ&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE&t=139

Comment: I added the .qrc file but the problem remains

Comment: ![ERROR](https://imgur.com/fSKnhJO)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than showing code and error messages as images, please copy and paste the text into your post. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about how to write good questions.

Comment: When you look closely his main.qml is also part of the qrc, but yours isn't.

Comment: I solved it by creating a new file and putting "Minimun required QT version" as 5.12. Doing this it automatically created qml.qrc and linked main.qml along with the others. But manually adding already with the minimum version 6.4 also worked later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your QML component to Qt resource file and then import the QML component from resource file.

Have a look at [The Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html) to know how to create and use a resource files.

Basically you need to do the following:

*Right Click Project Name in project explorer* --> *Add New* --> *Qt* --> *Qt Resource File*, to create a new resource file.

[image]

In the `main.qml` import the resource file as follows:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import "qrc:/qml/ui/BottomBar"

Window {
    width: 1280 * .5
    height: 720 * .5
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Tesla Infotainment")

    BottomBar {
        id: bottomBar
    }
}
```

Then run the application to get the desired result:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I solved it by creating a new file and putting "Minimun required QT version" as 5.12. Doing this it automatically created qml.qrc and linked main.qml along with the others. But manually adding already with the minimum version 6.4 also worked later. Thanks!